# Создание/удаление элемента html c помощью js

Tags: javascript, html

На html странице есть несколько элементов, 1-ый на странице есть, а 2-ой нет.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="insert magic">

Первый<select name = "1">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
</select>

Второй<select name = "2">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

С помощью чекбокса надо сделать так, чтобы при его нажатии первый элемент удалялся (Не скрывался), а второй создавался. Все что удалось сделать самому - скрыть, все остальные способы некорректно работали.

Comment: Решение должно быть на `vanilla js` или можно использовать `jqurey` ? Думаю основной смысл будет в том, что бы хранить второй `select` в js и подставлять его при выборе `checkbox`. Можно использовать легкий шаблонизатор, и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Можно использовать jquery, конечно.

Comment: если вам действительно не подходит вариант через `display: none`, то используйте `document.createElement()` для создания и `elem.remove()` для удаления элемента. но это создаёт лишнюю нагрузку, т.к. будет пересчитываться всё дерево элементов при каждом нажатии на `input`

Comment: Спасибо за советы, надеюсь получится

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  var newSelectHtml = 'Второй<select name="2"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';

  $('.js-checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.js-select-wrap').html(newSelectHtml);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="js-checkbox" type="checkbox">

<div class="js-select-wrap">
  Первый
  <select name="1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как-то так(Примерно аналогичное решение на vanilla.js.)
Хтмл:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="magic">

<div id="container">
  Первый
  <select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Vanilla.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('magic').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let container = document.getElementById('container')

    container.innerHTML = ''

    let select = document.createElement('select')
    select.innerHTML = "<option>1</option><option>2</option>"

    container.appendChild(select)

  })
})
```