# Ошибка обработки php

Tags: php, javascript, html

HTML страница передает обработчику php форму, на основе которой он делает вычисления и записывает в таблицу.

**Html**

```
<p>Раз
 <select name="raz">
<option value ="000" selected>---</option>
<option value="1">Да</option>
<option value="-1">Нет</option>
</select>

 Два<select name="dva">
<option value ="000" selected>---</option>
<option value="1">Есть</option>
<option value="-0.5">Не в полном объеме</option> 
<option value="-1">Нет</option>  
</select>
```

**Php**

```
if ($_POST['raz'] == "-1") {
$opervmesh = "Бла-бла1;";
$soglmp = "Бла-бла 2;";}

if ($_POST['dva'] < "0") {
$planlech = "Бла-бла 3;";
$nazleksr = "Бла-бла 4;";
$neobper = "-30";}
```

Все работало до того момента, пока мне не захотелось скрыть с помощью js часть html страницы ([мой прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486028/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-html-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-js)).

Если они скрыты, и я передаю значения обработчику, получается следующее - там, где в условии стоит "-1", ничего не происходит(и не должно), а там, где меньше 0 - срабатывают все условия. Счетчик цифр показывает 0, т.е никакие значения не передавались, но все равно они срабатывают. Почему так получается?

Comment: А зачем в условиях вы -1 и 0 заключаете в кавычки ? текстовый контекст для сравнений на >< не особо подходит

Comment: У вас "0" строка, сделайте integer `if ($_POST['dva'] <  0)`

Comment: Ну я не думал что это так важно. Сейчас попробую убрать

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Я думал проблема в чем-то более веселом :)